# Alternative to SQL Outer apply

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, dataset, tableadapter

My SQL query fetches stock Report dynamically from multiple tables. The query (written by someone else) works perfectly with the application. Now I want to create crystal reports from the query using TableAdapter in Dataset. But tableadapter rejects the query since it containing OUTER APPLY statements.

Is it possible to re-write the query without OUTER APPLY statements? I have only simple knowledge with SQL statements.

```
SELECT A.itemid as code,A.Description as name,InvOut.unit as Unit,Price as cost,A.salesrate, [quantity] = (isnull(InvIn.TotalIn,0)-isnull(InvReturn.TotalReturn,0)) - isnull(InvOut.TotalOut,0),(((isnull(Invin.TotalIn,0)-isnull(InvReturn.TotalReturn,0))-isnull(InvOut.TotalOut,0))*Price) as totalcost,((isnull(Invin.TotalIn,0)-isnull(InvOut.TotalOut,0))*salesrate) as totalsales,actualstock as ActualStock 
FROM itemdetails A OUTER APPLY(SELECT TotalIn=ISNULL(SUM(quantity),0)
FROM purchasedetails 
Where A.itemid =purchasedetails.itemid) InvIn OUTER APPLY(select 
TotalReturn=ISNULL(SUM(quantity),0)
FROM purchasereturndetails 
WHERE A.itemid=purchasereturndetails.itemid)InvReturn OUTER APPLY(SELECT unit,TotalOut=ISNULL(SUM(isnull((units.quantity*salesdetails.quantity),salesdetails.quantity)),0)
FROM salesdetails left join units on units.units=salesdetails.unit 
WHERE A.itemid = salesdetails.itemid group by unit ) InvOut;
```

Comment: Sure, use a left outer join

Comment: When i used it query returns The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound.

Comment: You need to alias it

Comment: how to do that with current query?? Im confused?

Comment: Make a VIEW from your Statement.
and  use the VIEW in the TableAdapter

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN (select...from....) as theAlias. Then, anywhere you reference this column, use theAlias.ColumnName

Comment: I failed...it is still showing thr problem of multipart identifier

Comment: Will anyone give me assistance if i give you my database file ???? Plsss help mee